# Cannot able to Bind http post response to dropdown list in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to **bind my post response to my dropdown list** but in drop-down text box it shows `[object Object]` there are two results from my request `ArticleID` and `Title` I need to show `Title` in dropdown and save the `ArticleID` of title in a variable for further usage. might be my logic is totally wrong, and I am lost.

**JSON Post response**

```
{
  ArticleID:1
  Title: Raven,
  ArticleID:4
  Title: sam,

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
     ngOnInit() {
      this.searchField.valueChanges

       .pipe(
          debounceTime(5000),
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          map((val) => {
               this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:3000/articles/articleslistData', { pubid: '3',pubdate: "2021-01-13" }).subscribe({
                next: data => {
                   console.log(data);

                },
                error: error => {
                    this.errorMessage = error.message;
                    console.error('There was an error!', error);
                }
            })
          })
      )
      .subscribe();
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="form-field col-lg-12">
<label class="label" for="message">Headline</label>
<input id="message" class="input-text js-input" type="text" *ngFor="let Article of ArticleList  
[value]="user.clientCode" [formControl]="searchField"> 
{{Article.Title}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response should ideally be an array:

```
const response = [{
  ArticleID:1
  Title: Raven
},{
  ArticleID:4
  Title: sam,
}]
```

Then, you can iterate over it and show it as options for dropdown:

```html
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let item of response" [value]="item.ArticleID">{{item.Title}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what about TS what do i need to fix in TS ?